# does phpadmin4 support postgresql 8.3?

Tags: greenplum

does phpadmin4 support postgresql 8.3?
currently in use greenplum 5.19

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry in subquery for table "typ"
LINE 62: typ.typrelid AS typoid,

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing when you see this error message?

Answer (score 0):

postgresql 9.0 doesn't support.
postgresql 9.4 - work good.

Answer (score 0):

phppgadmin isn't supported by gpdb ever and pgadmin isn't supported in greenplum after 5.2